# Using mod_rewrite instead of VirtualHost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using a hosting service that doesn't support VirtualHost, is it possible to use mod_rewrite to map domains to directories? If someone accesses domain1.com, I want the server to return the files from the `domain1` directory. I.e. going to `http://domain1.com/file.html` returns `/path/domain1/file.html`.

Here's what I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /domain1$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /domain2$1 [L]
```

This caused a 500, but my error log isn't giving me any useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for presence of `/domain/` in REQUEST_URI before routing to the same directory otherwise your rule will loop infinitely resulting into 500 error eventually.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!domain1/).*)$ domain1/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!domain2/).*)$ domain2/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really. mod_rewrite only kicks in after the web server has already figured out what directory to look for files in — if there isn't already some sort of virtual host directive pointing that domain to your document root, the web server won't end up looking at your .htaccess file at all.

It's possible to set up rewrite conditions based on `HTTP_HOST` (e.g, to enforce the use of a specific hostname where multiple hostnames already point to your site), but you can't use it to create completely new virtual hosts.

That all being said, those .htaccess directives generally shouldn't cause a 500 error. Is it possible that your host doesn't have mod_rewrite enabled at all? If so, have them turn it on, or find another web host that has it available. (This is a really basic, standard feature, and not having it would be ridiculous.)